# accessing the associated files after drag & drop in swift (Mac OS-X app)

Tags: swift, macos, 3d, desktop, gltf

I would like to allow users to drag & drop 3d model files such as glTF or FBX to import 3d models inside MacOS-X desktop App that I'm working on.

Problem is that these files reference texture files that are located separately from the main file. with App Sandbox, my understanding is that it is not possible to access these associated files unless all of them are drag & dropped. is there any way to access and read these associated files just by drag&drop the main file such as .gltf?

##### example

for example, glTF has directory structure like below and I need access to *.gltf* as well as *textures* folder.

I would like users to be able to drag & drop just the *scene.gltf* to import the model which necessitates read access to the *texture.png* file from the app.

- some folder

  - scene.gltf
  - textures

    - texture.png

#### requirements

- need the App Sandbox for Mac App Store

#### environemnt

- macOS-X 12 (Monterey)
- Xcode 13.2